# jQuery templates - Load another template within a template (composite)

Tags: jquery, templates, jquery-templates

I'm following this post by Dave Ward (http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading/) to load a composite templates for a Blog, where I have a total of 3 small templates (all in one file) for a blog post. In the template file, I have these 3 templates:

1. **blogTemplate**, where I render the "**postTemplate**"
2. Inside the "postTemplate", I would like to render another template that displays comments, I called this "**commentsTemplate**"
3. the "**commentsTemplate**"

Here's the structure of my json data:

```
blog
    Title
    Content
    PostedDate
    Comments (a collection of comments)
        CommentContents
        CommentedBy
        CommentedDate
```

For now, I was able to render the Post content using the code below:

***Javascript***

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('/GetPost', function (data) {
        $.get('/Content/Templates/_postWithComments.tmpl.htm', function (templates) {
            $('body').append(templates);
            $('#blogTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('#blogPost');
        });
    });
});
```

***Templates***

```
<!--Blog Container Templates-->
<script id="blogTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
<div class="latestPost">
    {{tmpl() '#postTemplate'}}
</div>
</script>
<!--Post Item Container-->
<script id="postTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
<h2>
    ${Title}</h2>
<div class="entryHead">
    Posted in <a class="category" rel="#">Design</a> on ${PostedDateString} <a class="comments"
        rel="#">${NumberOfComments} Comments</a></div>
${Content}
<div class="tags">
    {{if Tags.length}} <strong>Tags:</strong> {{each(i, tag) Tags}} <a class="tag" href="/blog/tags/{{= tag.Name}}">
        {{= tag.Name}}</a> {{/each}} <a class="share" rel="#"><strong>TELL A FRIEND</strong></a>
    <a class="share twitter" rel="#">Twitter</a> <a class="share facebook" rel="#">Facebook</a>
    {{/if}}
</div>
<!-- close .tags -->
<!-- end Entry 01 -->
{{if Comments.length}}
    {{each(i, comment) Comments}}
        {{tmpl() '#commentTemplate'}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
<div class="lineHor">
</div>
</script>
<!--Comment Items Container-->
<script id="commentTemplate" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
<h4>
    Comments</h4>
&nbsp;
<!-- COMMENT -->
<div id="authorComment1">
    <div id="gravatar1" class="grid_2">
        <!--<img src="images/gravatar.png" alt="" />-->
    </div>
    <!-- close #gravatar -->
    <div id="commentText1">
        <span class="replyHead">by<a class="author" rel="#">${= comment.CommentedBy}</a>on today</span>
        <p>
            {{= comment.CommentContents}}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- close #commentText -->
    <div id="quote1">
        <a class="quote" rel="#"><strong>Quote this Comment</strong></a>
    </div>
    <!-- close #quote -->
</div>
<!-- close #authorComment -->
<!-- END COMMENT -->
</script>
```

Where I'm having problem is at the

```
{{each(i, comment) Comments}}
        {{tmpl() '#commentTemplate'}}
{{/each}}
```

***Update - Example Json data when GetPost method is called***

```
{
   Id: 1,
   Title: "Test Blog",
   Content: "This is a test post asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf",
   PostedDateString: "2010-12-20",
   - Comments: [
     - {
          Id: 1,
          PostId: 1,
          CommentContents: "Test comments # 1, asdf asdf asdf",
          PostedBy: "User 1",
          CommentedDate: "2010-12-20"
        },
     - {
          Id: 2,
          PostId: 1,
          CommentContents: "Test comments # 2, ghjk gjjk gjkk",
          PostedBy: "User 2",
          CommentedDate: "2010-12-21"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried passing in `{{tmpl(comment) ...`, `{{tmpl(Comments) ...`, or leave `{{tmpl() ...` but none seems to work. I don't know how to iterate over the **Comments** collection and pass that object into the **commentsTemplate**.

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post some sample data, as JSON or an object literal?  Also, what is the actual problem you're having?  Is it rendering incorrectly? Not at all? JavaScript error?

Comment: In `#commentTemplate`, shouldn't it be `{{= CommentedBy}}` instead of `${Author}` and `{{= CommentContent}}` instead of `{{= Content }}`?

Comment: Hi Dave, I've just updated my question with the sample json data that got returned as well as fixing the "commentTemplate" to reflect what I really have. This code is using to displays the comment contents: `{{= comment.CommentContents}}`, Firebug says that `comment is not defined.` - As you can see from my code, `comment` is what I pass in as the parameter for `{{tmpl(comment) ...}}`. Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick note, if I move the `commentTemplate` to inside the `{{if Comments.length ... ... }}`, then it work... But it defeat the purposes of having small chunk of templates.

Comment: How can I pass data inside a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're referring to `comment` within `#commentTemplate`, but within that child template, `comment` is actually `this`. That is, you should be able to just refer to its properties directly if you're passing in the `comment` variable from the parent template:

```
<h4>
Comments</h4>
&nbsp;
<!-- COMMENT -->
<div id="authorComment1">
    <div id="gravatar1" class="grid_2">
        <!--<img src="images/gravatar.png" alt="" />-->
    </div>
    <!-- close #gravatar -->
    <div id="commentText1">
        <span class="replyHead">by<a class="author" rel="#">{{= CommentedBy}}</a>on today</span>
        <p>
            {{= CommentContents}}</p>
    </div>
    <!-- close #commentText -->
    <div id="quote1">
        <a class="quote" rel="#"><strong>Quote this Comment</strong></a>
    </div>
    <!-- close #quote -->
</div>
```